# Header and footer responsive issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am using Elementor header and footer kit for my Elementor page, but I don't know why the header and footer are streching more than it should be in mobile screen can't find out what css class making it
https://englanderdavis.com/elementor-37378/#Ebook

Comment: why you have a lot of nested divs. It's not a clean code

Comment: I have given a bit of manual coding just to remove the blanks pace before header and the after footer but could you please help me what causing this?

Comment: I can't really debug, your code is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT NOTE:  I realized this is not for the entire header,  when I looked at it on a mobile device, I noticed the image was the cause of my eyesore and addressed it.  sorry for this as I realized after re-reading your question, that the issue was the entire header...

it seems that Elementor has a max width that could be too big for the specific image you are trying to work with.  Sorry for the long time to answer, there was a lot of code to look through.

> /wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-34690.css?ver=1628743150

try setting the size to something else like 20% or it is currently set to 29%. you will have to play with it as I cannot reproduce all the files and test that would take me far too long.

This is the part you are looking to change the max-width

```html
.elementor-34690 .elementor-element.elementor-element-9837492 .elementor-image img {
    width: 51%;
    max-width: 29%;
    height: 45px;
}
```

You could also make the image more to the size you are looking for and remove the
class="elementor-image" from:
`<div class="elementor-image">`
altogether at line 1177.

However the image will be the same relative size (in this case in both positions by your size references depending on device) for that image on all devices.  meaning you would have to resize for the desktop.

Note: although a program like Elementor makes things easier to create,  it also convolutes the code with a lot of unnecessary entries and code that seemingly intentionally makes it hard for others to read or troubleshoot.  with that being said, I can only get you pretty close.

Unfortunately I cannot put too much more into this due to that and hopefully I got you on the right track:).

Comment: Thank you so much James, That was a clear explanation but the image is not the culprit which causing this issue, I have tried according to your suggestions, doesn't really reduce the width of entire header, It only reduces the the width of image